# Java Windows Thumbnail Toolbars

Tags: java, windows, thumbnail-toolbar

It's possible to use that feature in java, without creating own natives?
And for free. (No J7Goodies)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460#thumbbars